# Is it possible to get multiple hats with a single post?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash

Is it possible to get multiple hats with a single post?

For example, can you get the "on the road" hat and "bugdroid" hat with one question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only posted one question from the iOS app and got two badges for it:

[image: hats]

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible. I see no reason for a one-hat-per-post limit.

Also, multiple badges can be awarded on a single post. Hats seem to be awarded in a manner similar to badges, so that's another point in favor of multiple hats per post.

Answer (score -1):

Evidently not, I asked this with the Android app, but only received the "bugdroid" hat, but not the "on the road" hat.

Comment: FWIW I haven't gotten my On the Road hat for the question I asked half an hour ago.

Comment: @animuson I also didn't get selfie for this answer, so maybe there is something else at work here...

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It's only been 2 minutes. Have patience.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat But its Christmas and I want my hat.... *nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow*.